# Implement an ObjC protocol in Swift with pointer to incomplete type as a return value

Tags: swift, xcode, hopper

I'm trying to implement the HopperPlugin Objective-C protocol from the [Hopper SDK](https://github.com/0xc010d/HopperSDK) in a Swift class.

The compiler fails with an `"Type 'MyPlugin' cannot conform to protocol 'HopperPlugin' because it has requirements that cannot be satisfied"` error.

I imported all the SDK types in the bridging header. I used XCode's "Refactor/Generate Missing Function Definitions" to generate all the stubs but one is missing because the Hopper API makes use of a pointer to an incomplete type for HopperUUID as follows:

```
@class HopperUUID;
…
@protocol HopperPlugin <NSObject>
…
- (HopperUUID *)pluginUUID;
```

I'm guessing here, but it seems like this is why I am failing to meet the HopperPlugin protocol requirements. I don't create an instance of this type myself - I'm meant to call `HopperUUID! HPHopperServices.uuid(String!)` to get one but this method is also not defined (XCode auto-completion shows all the other HPHopperServices functions but not this one). Apple's docos suggest it might get mapped to an `OpaquePointer` but no function is generated with that signature either.

How do I diagnose what's going wrong? I've made use of the XCode's refactor and auto-completion to implement and identify the functions Swift knows about. Those relating to the incomplete HopperUUID type are not defined. Is there a more verbose compiler output that is being hidden from me?

What do I need to do to successfully implement this protocol in Swift?

Comment: The link doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: Check the generated header of HopperPlugin.h, compare the methods (including initializers) to the original HopperPlugin.h. You may find something lacking.

Comment: I've taken a look at all the build artefacts. No mention of HopperUUID at all (apart from the precompiled header .pch files) and nothing obvious there. I don't see a file named HopperPlugin.h anywhere in my project - the only such file on my system is in the SDK and the path to the SDK is set in the XCode project settings.

Comment: If you do not know how to open the generated header in SDK, you should have said so. Good luck.

Comment: I don’t know what I don’t know - that’s why I explained what I had checked  I checked all the build artefacts but have no idea how to find/open the generated header you refer to.

Comment: Include `@OOPer` to send notification to me. Try Cmd-click on `HopperPlugin` in your Swift code. And try adding dummy `@interface` into `...-Bridging-Header.h`, `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` `@interface HopperUUID: NSObject` `@end` before `#import "Hopper.h"`.

Comment: @OOPer Providing that minimal definition for the HopperUUID class interface does get things to compile. This looks like a workaround I can adopt and I can log a request to get the Hopper SDK fixed.

Comment: If I can be some help of you to create a nice app, I really am happy. Hope the SDK is fixed soon.